# working on redshift, have billions of records per day,the sql query and aggregates are too slow ? any tips of how can i make it faster

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

please help if any one has dealt with tables with billions of records and the aggregates that gives over 900 million  records is running too slow. tips to increase the perf of redshift.

```
select
  NODATA_records,
  main.hotel_id,
  main.site_id,
  main.eapid,main.tpid,
  main.client_id,
  main.message_type,
  dense_rank() over (order by NODATA_records desc) AS Causerank FROM
(
  SELECT
    SUM(a.No_data_records) AS NODATA_records,
    b.hotel_id,
    b.site_id,
    b.eapid,
    b.tpid,
    b.client_id,
    b.message_type
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS No_data_records,
      shopping_request_uid
    FROM dm.shopping_package
    WHERE 
      shopped_datetime::date = current_date-2
      GROUP BY shopping_request_uid 
  )a
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      count(*) AS No_data_records,
      shopping_request_uid,
      hotel_id,
      site_id,
      eapid,
      tpid,
      client_id,
      message_type
    FROM dm.shopping_product
    WHERE
      product_type='H'
      AND shopped_datetime::date =current_date-2
    GROUP BY shopping_request_uid,hotel_id,site_id,eapid,tpid,client_id,message_type
  )b
  ON a.shopping_request_uid=b.shopping_request_uid
  GROUP BY b.hotel_id,b.site_id,b.eapid,b.tpid,b.client_id,b.message_type
) main
```

Comment: Please provide more information so that we can assist you. For example, what are you doing that is "too slow" — is it when performing a query, or when inserting data? Can you show us the format of your tables and the query you are trying to run? What is the DISTKEY and SORTKEY for the table? There are _many_ ways to improve the performance of Redshift, but you will need to provide more information for us to provide any advice. Please Edit your question to add the additional information.

Comment: when I am performing a aggregate with many 6 fields of the table giving a result about 30 million combination of rows as a result. This is just a select query. The distkey is on session_guid and sort is on date_time

Comment: Have you tried an `EXPLAIN` to look at where the query is taking time? Also, would you have a simpler query that can demonstrate the situation?

Comment: Just an initial thought looking at the query... Why are you doing an `INNER JOIN` with a sub-select? It would presumably be more efficient to do an `INNER JOIN` on the tables directly. For example: `SELECT ... FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ... WHERE ...`. Also, I can't see the `session_guid` DISTKEY or the `date_time` SORTKEY being used in your query.

Comment: Hi John, the reason why i did not use the dist key is because it  is not required and the date_time field  that is sort key in the table is shopped_datetime . I am aggregating 2 tables to filter the relevnt records and running some analytic functions on it. What do you suggest will be a better appraoch please let me know

Comment: the reason why i am doing inner join on aggregate is because with direct join it might multiplythe records with direct join

Comment: Yes, but that is fine. The `WHERE` clause will then reduce the set of rows. The problem with using a sub-select is that it needs to create the temporary table with all the values, and then join against it. The temporary table will not take advantage of DISTKEY and SORTKEY optimizations. Give it a try!

Comment: there is another query which is just a aggregate table even that takes more than 3 hours to give results and eventually there is a timeout error select count(*) As No_of_records, hotel_id,site_id,eapid,tpid,client_id,message_type
from dm.shopping_product where 
shopped_datetime::date =current_date-2 and  <somemore>
group by hotel_id,site_id,eapid,tpid,client_id,message_type when i run it in tableau

Comment: Such a query would be helped by having `shopped_datetime` as the SORTKEY and one of the GROUP BY terms as the DISTKEY.

Comment: No that did not make it fast at all

Comment: Just thinking... Rather than using `shopped_datetime::date =current_date-2`, which doesn't allow a raw column value to be used, I wonder if you could use something like `shopped_datetime BETWEEN current_date-2 and current_date-1`?

Comment: no thats not helping either...can you suggest improvements that i can make working with the administrators

Comment: It is unlikely that any administrator settings would impact performance (except for changing the number/size of nodes). Queries are typically optimized good use of `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY`, and query improvements based on `EXPLAIN` results.